# Boolean algebra: How does the imply operator work?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am conflicted because our professor said that "(not) A implies B only and only if A and B = 0" which doesn't match with what I found on Wikipedia or other books on Boolean algebra: "A implies B = (not) A or B". Are the two equivalent, or one of them is wrong? Our professor also said that the imply operator is similar to a negated AND...

Comment: Have you been introduced to De Morgan's laws?

Comment: Also, have you written out truth tables for each statement? At the least, you can try out some values: $A = 0$ and $B = 1$

Comment: the tables are different that is the reason I am asking this question...

Comment: Then it seems to me that you already have the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(not A) => B if only false when A is true and B is false.  So if A and B are both true (not A) => B is true.  But A and B = 0 is false.  So these are not equivalent.

not (A => B) is only true when (A => B) is false.  (A => B) is only false when A is true and B is false.  So if A and B are both false, A and B = 0 is true but not(A => B) is false.

You must be misquoting your professor.

A *or* B = 0 is only true if A and B are both false.  (not) A => B is only true if A and B are both false.

So that must be what your professor meant.